# Unix find with wildcard directory structure

Tags: regex, unix, find, grep

I am trying to do a `find` where I can specify wildcards in the directory structure then do a grep for www.domain.com in all the files within the data directory.

ie

```
find /a/b/c/*/WA/*/temp/*/*/data -type f -exec grep -l "www.domain.com" {} /dev/null \;
```

This works fine where there is only one possible level between c/*/WA.

How would I go about doing the same thing above where there could be multiple levels between C/*/WA?

So it could be at

```
/a/b/c/*/*/WA/*/temp/*/*/data
```

or

```
/a/b/c/*/*/*/WA/*/temp/*/*/data
```

There is no defined number of directories between `/c/` and `/WA/`; there could be multiple levels and at each level there could be the `/WA/*/temp/*/*/data`.

Any ideas on how to do a find such as that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a `for` loop to find the `WA` directories, then go from there:

```
for DIR in $(find /a/b/c -type d -name WA -print); do
    find $DIR/*/temp/*/*/data -type f \
        -exec grep -l "www.domain.com" {} /dev/null \;
done
```

You may be able to get all that in a single command, but I think clarity is more important in the long run.

Comment: The second `find` makes the shell do the hard work, and uses `find` just to check that `data` is in fact a regular file, not a directory (or other 'non-file').

Comment: I thnk this may have worked - I'm just checking to see if it is correct! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no spaces in the paths, then I'd think in terms of:

```
find /a/b/c -name data -type f |
grep -E '/WA/[^/]+/temp/[^/]+/[^/]+/data' |
xargs grep -l "www.domain.com" /dev/null
```

This uses `find` to find the files (rather than making the shell do most of the work), then uses the `grep -E` (equivalent to `egrep`) to select the names with the correct pattern in the path, and then uses `xargs` and `grep` (again) to find the target pattern.